# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value' - Issue Concerning "Neural Style Audio Transfers"

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Edit #1:

Thanks to the keen insights of @Chaos_is_harmony a bit of deprecated Tensorflow syntax has been discovered:

`net.get_shape()`
whereas it is now
`net.ref()`

While this resolves the question that is the topic of this post, it does prompt a new, perhaps related error:
`'Reference' object is not iterable`

Original post:

Hello hello StackOverflow,

I'm an amateur musician who's not particularly savvy at programming (took a couple Python courses at Uni over a decade ago and haven't gone any further, let alone engaged with it, since), but returned to it today, and have been trying all afternoon, to run Dmitri Ulyanov's "Neural Style Audio Transfer" in order to generate and iterate samples from pre-existing bits of sound design I've done, or to convolve what I've done with what others have done in styles I'm less proficient at. It seemed more or less usable without much coding so I thought appropriate to try. In any case, Dmitri's project's details may be found here: https://github.com/DmitryUlyanov/neural-style-audio-tf

That is what I'm kinda good at, not programming nor assessing code, so I must apologize for my ignorance in advance, both in my description of the issue and my ability to track/implement your responses should I receive any. Nonetheless, there were a few extant issues with running the notebook I was able to resolve by importing "tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf". But it did not fix all the issues.

I am stuck at one error in the "Optimize" portion of the notebook:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'

Here's how it looks in context (I'm not sure which part of the code is relevant so as to copy it directly in here, I'm sorry...):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZP81.jpg

Here's a video of the notebook being run, cell by cell if that's helpful:
https://streamable.com/tqzmwf

I'm not sure what else might be helpful to mention other than I'm using Python 3 as the kernel (as indicated in the video.) Hopefully I've not given you all too little to go on here, as again, I've sort of jumped into the deep end of things I really know almost nothing about. If it were more than just this one error I would have let it go and not bothered you all; but I also thought it prudent to ask this in posterity for other amateur musicians who may need some guidance in how to use ML tools for music creation and might thus come across this post in the future. All silly justification that aside, let me know if there's anything more I can detail!

Much obliged~!

Comment: Next to the lambda function where it says ```net.get_shape()```, try instead ```net.ref()```.

Comment: @Chaos_Is_Harmony Hello, my goodness, hello, thank you for throwing me a line, I'm pathetically grateful! I've gone and tried your method, which reads as follows:

>_, height, width, number = map(lambda i: i.value, net.ref())

and I do see a resolution to the extant error, but now replaced by another: 

>"TypeError: 'Reference' object is not iterable"

Let's see how far I can get with this one! Thank you for setting me on a new path with new challenges, I have to suppose this is getting closer to a result!

Comment: Did it work? If so, I'll make it an answer and provide a link to the reference that made me suggest that.

Comment: God I am sorry this is my first time using StackExchange so I was not aware it had to be a shift+return for line breaks in comments; didn't mean to post my reply when I did. As above, it's returned a new error, but that may be one I can solve, so I will tinker with it for a bit before troubling you further! Thank you so much for stepping in to be of help here tonight!

Comment: You can update your post with the attempt at using ```ref()``` and the new error you got. Might help others facing a similar issue in the future.

Comment: @Chaos_Is_Harmony Done and done! Thank you ever so much for your assistance and for helping me format my post so it can be as useful as possible to others!

Comment: No worries; it's best for all involved. The new error seems to be saying that ```Reference``` types cannot be iterated over--which is necessary when passing it to the lambda function.

Comment: How about trying just ```net.shape``` instead of ```net.ref()```? Wish I had more guided advice; I've never used Tensorflow before and am just digging into the docs to see what you can throw at the problem...

Comment: Ah, regrettably that did not ameliorate the issue, but thank you for sticking with it! And no worries. I'm going to simply table this idea for now until I'm more capable, can't really lose a whole weekend to fixing something that was only a good idea if I didn't have to fix it at all! Many thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Tensforflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#get_shape) for `get_shape()`, it says it is a deprecated method and should instead be replaced with `ref()`.

Comment: no that's for get_experimental_ref, the function described above it